# How to capture the screen behind of a see-through panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form, containing `panel1` and `panel1` is of green background and the form `TransparencyKey` is also set to green and now instead of panel, what's behind it shows up. So I added a button and added this code to capture the screen which I see through the panel:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
bmp.Save(@"F:\Image.bmp");
MessageBox.Show("Save Complete!");
```

But the image saved is of green color only! Any way to save what's shown behind the `panel1` on screen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Graphics.CopyFromScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get a screenshot of screen. Here is a method which helps you to get a screenshot of given bounds of the screen:

```
public Bitmap GetDesktopImage(Rectangle bounds)
{
    var bm = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(bounds.Location, new Point(0, 0), bounds.Size);
    }
    return bm;
}
```

Then it's enough to pass the screen bounds of the panel to the method. To get the screen bounds of the panel, you can pass its [`Bound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) property to [`RectangleToScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.rectangletoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) method of its [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var bounds = panel1.Parent.RectangleToScreen(panel1.Bounds);
var image = GetDesktopImage(bounds);
//image.Save(@"d:\bm.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```